# port forwarding to access services on servers behind NAT

Tags: openvpn, nat, forwarding, udp, linux-networking

I have some security camera systems in different locations, each location does have internet, the ISP is NATing all the IPs so theres no way to open ports to my systems.

My solution was to rent a VPS with Debian, install OpenVPN server on it, place a computer with openVPN client next to each system, and enable routing on it.

The final step is to redirect different ports on the server to different sites, I used rinetd (which is most probably one of my problems)

The TCP connections are working, I can see the HTML pages of the security systems by accessing the address of the VPS:port, but no video is being streamed. my guess is that it is because it is using UDP and rinetd doesn't support it.

say server IP is 199.188.x.x and security system IP is 192.168.1.55, and they both have a vpn link in subnet 10.8.0.x

So now to the question: how can I setup the server to send the UDP video to a client connected in this way? also any suggestions to improve my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a second vpn between the vps and the client and route the traffic between the 2 vpns.

Assuming camera systems are on site A, VPS on site B and client on site C, your infrastruture would look like :

```
  +-> B <- +
  |        |
  A        C
```

With each arrow representing an ssl vpn.

Comment: Good thinking, but I must leave the client out of VPN. otherwise I will have to manually configure all client devices, and some of them are mobile devices.